# highlighting a number threshold in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to call jqGrids loadComplete function and highlight specific cells in a column that meet or exceed a specific threshold.  Here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
loadComplete: function() {

    var threshold = '5';

    // How do I iterate through each row and check for a value exceeding my threshold?

    $.each(rows,function(index, value) {
       //alert("index: " + index);
       grid.jqGrid('setCell',index,"name", '', {'color':'red'});

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       loadComplete: function() {
        var cssGreen = {'background-color':'#6DFF6D',
            'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = \'#D9FFD9\', endColorstr = \'#6DFF6D\')',
            'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #D9FFD9, #6DFF6D 2px, #D9FFD9 4px)'};
        var cssRed = {'background-color':'#FF6D6D',
            'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = \'#FECECD\', endColorstr = \'#FF6D6D\')',
            'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FECECD, #FF6D6D 2px, #FECECD 4px)'};
        var columns = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
        var ids = jQuery("#gridMain").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            var columnName = columns[i].name;
            for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                var cell = grid.jqGrid("getCell", ids[j], columnName);
                grid.setCell(ids[j], columnName, '', '', {'title':colNameData[i]}); 
                if (cell != null && cell.indexOf("%g") >= 0) {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[j], columns[i].name, '', cssGreen);
                } else if (cell != null && cell.indexOf("%r") >= 0) {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[j], columns[i].name, '', cssRed);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this example is what your looking for. The function loops through the cells, if the celldata contains '%g' it applies the CSS syle defined towards top. Just set the CSS to whatever highlighting style you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use afterInsertRow event:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

There's a rowData and a rowElem parameters so it seems you have everything you need. (I would add a class to the cells and set the color with css)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using jqgrid's [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

For instance you can do something like this:

```
<script>
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true, formatter:currencyFmatter},
      ...
   ]
...
});

function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   if (cellvalue > 5){
     return "<div style='color:red'>"+cellvalue+"</div>";
   }else{
     return cellvalue;
   }
}
</script>
```